# Can't get the range from excel worksheet c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I'm trying to create a chart from a given range.
I have values between A1 and BQ11.

If I do the following:  `chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1", "J11"];`, I get the graph correctly.

However, if I do this: `chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1", "BQ11"];`, the generated graph in incorrect...x axis in now y axis and y axis is now x axis.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you need to provide more code...

Comment: hmmm that seems strange, but you can set the x and y programmatically, via the SeriesCollection's `.XValues` and `.Values`.  This would allow you to override whatever assumption that Excel might be making.